# Fit a Logit/Probit regression model in R using Maximum Likelihood

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, least-squares, mle

A simple question here:

I'd like to know if there is any function in R that can fit a **logit/probit** regression model using **maximum likelihood method**?

Currently, I'm using OLS method given by function `glm` (I hope it does use OLS method)... I read somewhere that probit/logit model with OLS method may have incidental parameter problem. So I'd like to try MLE method.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `glm` function maximizes likelihood using  `iteratively re-weighted least squares` (IWLS), just set `family` parameter to `binomial`

Comment: Thank you! I see the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Maju116's comment is correct. `glm()` doesn't use ordinary least squares, it uses [iteratively reweighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares); as the linked Wikipedia article says

> IRLS is used to find the maximum likelihood estimates of a generalized linear model

The default link for the binomial family is logit, so either `glm(...,family=binomial)` or `glm(...,family=binomial(link="logit"))` will fit logistic (logit) regression. `glm(...,family=binomial(link="probit"))` will fit probit regression.

If you are currently using `glm(...)` *without* an explicit `family` argument, then you are assuming Gaussian errors, which does mean that you'll get the same answers as ordinary least squares (`lm()`) (which are the maximum likelihood estimates for a data set with Gaussian (normally) distributed errors). For clarity and efficiency, it's generally best to use `lm()` rather than `glm()` with the default family when you want to do OLS.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I'm using `glm(..., family=binomial(link="probit"))` now. I will use `lm()` for OLS.